# SQL: update value based on following rows data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table `customer_service_types` in `phpmyadmin` with these fields:

```
id (int) | customer_id (int) | service_type_int (int) | price (decimal) | created (datetime) | card (tinyint)
```

Here are some entries:

[image: rows]

The application when the user adds a new service for a customer with a custom created date, is creating another service with id : 3 (payment) with today's date. I want to update all payments with the date of the following services.

So what I want to do is update the `created` field of the payments with the `created` value of the **following** services for specific client. So for example I need to update `created` of `id`: 168 with the value of `created` for the same `customer_id` but only of the following row if it has `service_type_id` != 3.

Tried so far:

```
UPDATE customer_service_types cst
    SET cst.created = (SELECT created
                FROM customer_service_types cst2
                WHERE cst.id = (cst2.id - 1) AND cst2.service_type_id <> 3
               ) 
    WHERE cst.service_type_id = 3;
```

But I get this error:

> You can't specify target table 'cst' for update in FROM clause

And I don't know if this query will produce the desired result

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted thus far?

Comment: Most people here want sample data (and expected result) as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @haag1 I updated my post with what I have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer your subquery to a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) form instead. Try the following:

```
UPDATE customer_service_types AS cst 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, created
  FROM customer_service_types
  WHERE service_type_id <> 3
) AS cst2 
  ON cst.id = (cst2.id - 1)

SET cst.created = cst2.created 
WHERE cst.service_type_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join`:

```
UPDATE customer_service_types cst JOIN
       customer_service_types cstnext
       ON cstnext.id = cst.id and cstnext.service_type_id <> 3
    SET cst.created = cstnext.created
    WHERE cst.service_type_id = 3;
```